# Reevaluate historical locks on some books

Tags: discussion, specific-question, locked-question

While stumbling across an update link project for Stroustrup's homepage (as I write this there are about two dozen posts that link to an old page that doesn't exist anymore), I found two book questions that have been historically locked.

---

The first is: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/143553/what-are-good-books-for-learning-c11 with 17k views

> I'm just starting to get interested in C++11 (late I know). Does anyone have any recommendations for books available that cover the new features in depth?

It has two link only answers. One of the links is dead.

---

The other is: [What's the worst programming book you've ever read?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/6974/whats-the-worst-programming-book-youve-ever-read) with 9k views and 29 answers.

We do book reviews poorly. We do rant about a book review even worse.  Most of these books are so incredibly dated that at best, the only thing people would do is use one for a monitor stand. The question is about books that have no redeeming quality and five years later, the question itself has no redeeming qualities.

---

Please consider deleting both of these questions. Neither reflect well on Programmers.SE.

Comment: I agree, nuke any "resource request" question regardless of its lock status.

Comment: The C++11 is terrible, no idea why I locked it. Gone.